# how to make use of hashmap in following code

Tags: java, hashmap

how do i make use of hashmap in this code.i have rosters that hold ArrayList of students. i know hashmap use key and value pair, but i'm confuse on what would be my key and value if i use hashmap in the following classes that use arraylist.

this is my modify class where i make some modificaton on basis of user

```
//input that i get in may main class. 

public class modify{
  ArrayList<Roster> rList;

  public modify{
    rList = new ArrayList<Roster>();
  }

  public void addRoster(){
    System.out.println("Enter name for roster: ");
    String name = newObj.nextLine();
    //Teacher t = new Teacher().addTeacher();
    Student s = new Student().addStudent();
    Roster addR = new Roster(s, name, 0);
    rList.add(addR);    
    System.out.println("New Roster Created: ");

  }//end of addRoster

  /*
  code
  */

}//end of class
```

this is my roster class. it hold the arralist of students.

```
public class Roster{

  int id;
  String name;
  List<Student> students;

  public Roster(Student s, String name, int id){

    this.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    this.students.add(s);
    this.id = ranObj.rand();
    this.name = name;
  }//constructor
}//end of roster
```

this is my student class

```
public class Student {
  private int studentId;
  public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    super( firstName, lastName, age);
    this.studentId = ranObj.rand();
  }

  public String toString(){
    return String.format("Student:\n" +
      " Id = %d\n" +
      " Age = %d\n" +
      " firstName = %s\n" +
      " lastName = %s\n\n" +
      " ",getStudentId(),super.getAge(),     
      super.getFirstName(),super.getLastName());
  }// end of tostring class

}//end of student
```

Comment: Please make an effort to format your posts nicely.

Comment: Another zero effort question

Comment: You should be hiding the collection you use to store students inside Roster and not exposing that implementation in any way.  If you do that, it's easy to swap out List and use Map instead.  It would make sense to use a unique key (e.g. student id, name, etc.) as the Map key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your class roster

```
 public class Roster{ //attributes of Roster.
             int id; // Assuming this should be unique for each Object.
            String name;  //I don't know for what purpose u have used this.
            List<Student> students; //list of Students
```

So You Want to store `List<Roaster>` into a `HashMap` so, If you know that `keys` should be unique declared in `HashMap` then choose only that attribute which makes every single `Object` of Class `Roster` Unique.

**(only suggesting as per my assumption)**

> Note :- In my perspective attribute `id` is unique for your `Roster` Class. So, you should make `id` as a Key to store a bulk of Object.

Your `HashMap` declaration should be like That

```
Map<Integer, Roster> obj_hMapRoster = new HashMap<Integer, Roster>();
//int for key and Roster for Adding Object of Roster Classs.
```

in this declared `Map` you can put Id as Key which is `Integer`. You can Store easily. for each different Object of Roster `key` is mapped.

Thank You